# How to transform __dict__ key name with "_" into "-"?

Tags: python

I have a very simple Class that has couple properties name with underscore. Is it is possible to convert those underscored names to `"-"` when I call `__dict__`?

For example:

```
>>> class class1:
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.a_key = 1
...
>>> o = class1()
>>> o.__dict__
{'a_key': 1}
```

Is there a way to convert `a_key` to `a-key`? I can write my own to dict function, but I just want it to be dynamic as I may want to add more fields later.

Comment: You can just use `{k.replace("_", "-"):v for k,v in o.__dict__.items()`

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Are you actually trying to make the attribute use a `-` instead of a `_`? Because while you *can* put any string in a `dict`, you won't be able to actually use `my_object.my_attribute` because that only works with valid identifiers

Comment: You can, but you probably shouldn't be using `__dict__` directly in the first place.

Comment: `setattr(self, 'a-key', 1)`, but why?

Comment: If you do this you will not be able to access the attribute using `o.a-key` because `a_key` is not a valid Python identifier name. As others have already asked, why do you want to do this? This sound like it might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Correction: What I should have said was "…because `a-key` is not a valid Python identifier name."